# Writing a row in Python, what is the best data structure to use?

Tags: python, string, list, csv

I am trying to write headers for a .csv file (1 row)

My current way of doing this, I think is inefficient

```
    headers = "Color:," + color + ',' \
              "State:," + state + ',' \
              "Age," + str(age)

    writer.writerow((headers.split(','))
```

So the first row of every csvfile looks like

> Color:, Red, State:, California, Age:, 22

Is there a better way in doing this, instead of a string...

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you creating a string then splitting it again?!

Comment: And why are you including values in your header row?

Comment: Lol cause I'm a bad programmer :(.. I tried using a list, but it's not writing to the csv file as I want it too @jonrsharpe

Comment: What precisely does that mean? Please give a [mcve] rather than a vague description.

Comment: You want these header prefixes in every row instead of using one line as a csv header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the string concatenation and make a list instead of having to split on commas.

```
headers = ['Color:', color, 'State:', state, 'Age:', str(age)]
writer.writerow(headers)
```

This will accomplish what you have already but I am concerned about data in the header. What is this accomplishing?

Comment: The files basically use two headers.. The first row contain just some initial data.